# Keyboard visibility listener when activity is not resizable

Tags: java, android, xml, kotlin

I have an `Activity` where there are 2 `EditText`. I have applied `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing"`. When the user clicks on the `EditText`, the soft keyboard opens to enter some value in it. I want to set some other `View`'s visibility to `Gone` when the soft keyboard opens and also when the soft keyboard closes from the `EditText` on the back button press. Then I want to set some other `View`'s visibility to `Visible`.

I have tried serveral solution but they are not working due to `adjustNothing` applied on the `Activity`.
I have also used following keyboard visibilty watcher library but it's also not working due to `adjustNothing`.

`implementation 'net.yslibrary.keyboardvisibilityevent:keyboardvisibilityevent:3.0.0-RC2'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to set a global layout listener to the root view of your Activity to detect changes in the height of the view. When the height of the view decreases, you can assume that the keyboard has opened. When the height of the view increases, you can assume that the keyboard has closed.

```
val rootView = findViewById<View>(android.R.id.content)
    rootView.viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(object :
        ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener {
        override fun onGlobalLayout() {
            val heightDiff = rootView.rootView.height - rootView.height
            if (heightDiff > dpToPx(this@YourActivity, 200f)) { // if more than 200 dp, it's probably a keyboard...
                // do something here
            } else {
                // do something here
            }
        }
    })
    
   
    fun dpToPx(context: Context, dp: Float): Int {
        return TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, dp, context.resources.displayMetrics).toInt()
    }
```